# Zepto / jQuery plugin base

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

I am looking for a starting point to code plugins, primarily  for Zepto.js (with fall back for jQuery). These will provide reusable functions for Tumblr theming.

However, I can't seem to find anything in depth about writing a plugin (with Zepto) as the example, apart from a small snippet on the Zepto site: http://zeptojs.com/

The code below is pieced together from reading various 'jQuery' plugin tutorials, but I am not 100% sure how solid it is.

```
;(function($){
    $.extend($.fn, {
        pluginName: function(el, options) {
            // Set defaults
            this.defaults = {
                option: 'option',
                onComplete: function() {}
            };
            // Combine defaults / options
            var settings = $.extend({}, this.defaults, options);
            // Do stuff
            $.each(this, function() {

            });
            // Call back if needed
            settings.onComplete.call(this);
            // Return `this` for chain ability
            return this;
        }
    });
}(window.Zepto || window.jQuery));
```

According to the Zepto documentation, my plugins method will be added to the Zepto object. Is this acceptable?

I would also like the option to use private / public functions contained in the plugin for flexibility.

I apologise if my questions come across as confusing or novice, but any help / improvements would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could check the [jQuery Boilerplate](http://jqueryboilerplate.com/) for a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks @JosephtheDreamer that's where I got bits for the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks fine to me, but then again it's sample (boilerplate) code ;)

- Consider `"use strict"`;
- If it was not for the `onComplete`, you could simply `return` the result of `$.each`

I like your options handling, graceful fallback to jQuery, style, it's all good.